# Do Bigquery charge if table gets deleted via retention period?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a data of around 150 GB data and I want to store that in bigquery using DML statements.

Here is the pricing model for that.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#dml

According to them they will charge for deleting the table via DML.

If I create a table with retention period will I be charged for that? considering I will always insert data. I am not bothering about cost for inserting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the DML Specifications, Google will charge for the *deletion of rows if done using DML statement* (or using `DELETE` command in their SQL). The reason being: BigQuery will have to scan rows to delete them (like `DELETE FROM mydataset.mytable WHERE id=xxx;`, etc.), so you will have to pay for the number of bytes scanned before deleting the resulting rows.

You can always delete your entire table from your dataset for free by either using BigQuery UI or `bq` command line utility.

Also, you will be charged for the storage costs in BigQuery (irrespective of usage). Meaning: you will pay for the number of bytes your data is occupying on Google disks.

Comment: If I delete from using SDK... `bigquery.tables().delete(projectId, scratchSchema, table).execute()` will it run DDL or DML statement?

Comment: Not sure if it runs DDL statement in the background or not, but its surely not DML because its not scanning anything in the table prior to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

- BigQuery charges for deleting *from* a table, not deleting a table. Executing a `DROP TABLE` statement is free.
- Creating tables is free, unless you create a table from the result of a table, in which case see [query pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries) to calculate your costs.
- The cost of storage is based on the number of bytes stored and how long you keep the data. See [storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage) for more details.